# Can I have a pointer to an item in an allocatable array component?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a user-defined type `vector`. In another type, I have an allocatable array of vectors. I want to have a pointer to a single vector from this allocatable array. So I thought I would do this:

```
type another_type
  type(vector),allocatable,target::my_vectors(:)
end type
```

and

```
type(vector),pointer::pointed_vec
```

But when I compile, the compiler complains that:

```
This attribute specification is not valid for a component definition statement.
```

Can I have a pointer to a single item from an allocatable array? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Only actual instances of variables or derived types may have the `TARGET` attribute.  So, the allocatable in the second type definition cannot be a target as this is just a description of what the type should look like, a template if you like.

However, you can give a real instance of the type the `TARGET` attribute and then point to any of it's component parts with appropriately declared Fortran pointers.

**Editted**:  An alternative, and probably more what you're after, is to give the vector array in the type the `POINTER` attribute only, which implicitly makes it both legitimate pointee and may be used to allocate memory.  You just have to make sure that you don't reassign the pointer (`v` in example below) after you've used it to allocate the memory, because then you'll have a leak.

```
PROGRAM so_pointtype

  IMPLICIT NONE

  TYPE vec
    INTEGER :: x = 2, y = 3
  END TYPE vec

  TYPE foo
    TYPE(vec),POINTER :: v(:)
  END TYPE foo

  TYPE(foo) :: z
  TYPE(vec),DIMENSION(:),POINTER :: p2 => NULL()

  ALLOCATE(z%v(3))

  PRINT*,z%v(:)

  p2 => z%v(:)

  PRINT*,p2

END PROGRAM so_pointtype
```

Comment: Makes sense, given the error, but that's quite frustrating! It means that what I do inside my type is dependent on whether I've declared something further up in the type hierarchy as target. Hmmm.

Comment: The problem is that my array of vecs is allocatable, which is what the compiler originally complained about. But now I've set something higher up as a target.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can point to a single item in an allocatable array, but your array `my_vectors` is a scalar, which cannot have the `allocatable` attribute.  Maybe it's that declaration that's giving the compiler error.  With gfortran I get a compile-time message:

```
  TYPE(vector),ALLOCATABLE,TARGET :: my_vectors
                                1
Error: Scalar object 'my_vectors' at (1) may not be ALLOCATABLE
```

Try declaring as `my_vectors(:)`.

Comment: Good spot, but that was just me failing to remember my code correctly. I do have an array declaration, not a scalar...

Comment: Also I mis-read that your allocatable was also within a type definition.  Unsure of large edit etiquette, so added new answer.

Comment: did not work for me. kept getting the error in the original post.