# Pointers as components of derived types

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I understand from this answer  ([Fortran copy of pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854078/fortran-copy-of-pointer)) that I should try to use allocatable arrays rather than array pointers as components of derived types.  I intend to do so but am locked into my current code for the next year and need to be able to use it and understand it until I can make the bigger and better changes next year.

I also think this question is of some general interest because I think fortran behavior here is pretty unintuitive although apparently correct.  So there is likely value in better understanding how and why it works (or else I assume the compiler wouldn't let us do this at all, right?).

Sorry for the longish intro.  I'll try to do this as one annotated program that has been whittled down as much as possible:

```
program main

   type tRet
      real :: agi
      real :: wages_tgt(5)          ! compiler won't let me declare as
                                    ! target but later I point to this
      real, pointer :: wages(:)
   end type tRet

   type(tRet), target :: ret             ! I don't quite understand 
   type(tRet), target :: orig1, orig2    ! why but compiler insists
                                         ! these be targets
   ret%wages => ret%wages_tgt(1:1)
   ret%wages = (/ 11. /)
   orig1 = ret
   ret%wages = (/ 99. /)
   orig2 = ret
```

That's the top half of the program, here's some results with print output shown as comments to the right:

```
   ! This is not want I want and I was surprised, but it is kind
   ! of explained in the other answer why this happens, so OK...

   print *, "orig1%wages ", orig1%wages    ! 99.
   print *, "orig2%wages ", orig2%wages    ! 99.


   ! But if I copy from orig1 or orig2 into ret then it
   ! works like I wanted it to work in the first place!
   ! But I don't completely understand why it works...

   ret = orig1
   print *, "ret%wages   ", ret%wages      ! 11.
   print *, "orig1%wages ", orig1%wages    ! 11.
   print *, "orig2%wages ", orig2%wages    ! 11.

   ret = orig2
   print *, "ret = orig2 "
   print *, "ret%wages   ", ret%wages      ! 99.
   print *, "orig1%wages ", orig1%wages    ! 99.
   print *, "orig2%wages ", orig2%wages    ! 99.

end program main
```

I'm happy for any nice explanation of what is going on here.  The irony here, I guess, is that I'm not so worried about why this is a bad idea but rather why does my workaround seem to work fine?

Or maybe the easiest way to summarize my question is:  **What exactly is pointing to what?**

Compiler:  GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)

Comment: When is your `associated` debugging output put in your code? At the end, after `ret=orig2`?

Comment: Regarding your comments about what may be targets: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3948210/3157076) partly addresses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that when you copy a derived data type, different things happen for each component of the derived type. When you do `orig1 = ret`:

- Declared arrays, such as `wages_tgt`, are assigned new values. This is equivalent to saying `orig1%wages_tgt = ret%wages_tgt`. Each of these arrays occupy **separate** places in memory.
- Pointers, such as `wages`, are made to point to wherever the source pointer is currently pointing. This is equivalent to saying `orig1%wages => ret%wages`. The destination of both of these pointers is the **same** location in memory. In the example here, the only location in memory ever pointed to by any `wages` is `ret%wages_tgt`.

With that in mind, your result makes sense to me. Adding some selective additional annotations:

```
ret%wages => ret%wages_tgt(1:1)

ret%wages = (/ 11. /)   ! so wages_tgt = 11 also

orig1 = ret             ! This is BOTH a copy and re-point
                        ! * orig1%wages_tgt =  ret%wages_tgt (11)
                        ! * orig1%wages     => ret%wages_tgt

ret%wages = (/ 99. /)   ! this changes ret%wages & ret%wages_tgt
                        ! to 99 and also orig1%wages since it is
                        ! also pointing to ret%wages_tgt.

                        ! note that orig1%wages_tgt is UNCHANGED 
                        ! (still 11) but nothing is pointing to it!
```

Lower down in the code...

```
ret = orig1  ! ret%wages_tgt = orig1%wages_tgt (11) 
             ! no repointing actually happens this time b/c we have
             ! set up a circular relationship between all the
             ! pointers such that ALL of them point to ret%wages_tgt
```

Comment: I should add, the part that was most confusing about this is that the copies of ret to orig1 & orig2 essentially set this up into a **circular** pointer resolution which I know understand pretty well (I think) but it makes correct usage pretty unintuitive IMO, even if it is correct and expected according to the f90 language spec.

Comment: The edits are good. I didn't really understand what was confusing, so I think I over-explained the issue.

Comment: The explanation was great (especially the text at the top), I would be happy to have more over-explaining for many of the fortran answers here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a bonus answer to a question I had here but didn't really make explicit.  The confusing aspect to how fortran works here IMO is that you end up with circular pointers that leads to unintuitive behavior (even if it correct according to the f90 specification).

But by explicitly pointing from `orig1%wages` to `orig1%wages_tgt` (and similarly for `orig2`) you can avoid the circular pointers, at least to some degree.  Here's the same code as in the question, but with the some explicit pointing added.

```
ret%wages => ret%wages_tgt(1:1)
ret%wages = (/ 11. /)

orig1 = ret
orig1%wages => orig1%wages_tgt(:size(ret%wages))   ! *** added code ***

ret%wages = (/ 99. /)

orig2 = ret
orig2%wages => orig2%wages_tgt(:size(ret%wages))   ! *** added code ***

print *, "orig1%wages ", orig1%wages    ! 11.
print *, "orig2%wages ", orig2%wages    ! 99.

ret = orig1
print *, "ret%wages   ", ret%wages      ! 11.
print *, "orig1%wages ", orig1%wages    ! 11.
print *, "orig2%wages ", orig2%wages    ! 99.

ret = orig2
print *, "ret = orig2 "
print *, "ret%wages   ", ret%wages      ! 99.
print *, "orig1%wages ", orig1%wages    ! 11.
print *, "orig2%wages ", orig2%wages    ! 99.
```

Hence, by keeping `orig1` & `orig2` pointers distinct (and avoiding circular pointing), you can copy `orig1` to `ret` without the side effect of changing `orig2`.

A remaining strange thing here, however, is that if I test with associated, it claims `orig1` does not point to `orig2` even though I explicitly pointed in that way and the behavior seems to also reflect that:

```
print *, "assoc?", associated(orig1%wages, orig1%wages_tgt) ! F
```